# error installing tensorflow on ubuntu mate 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-mate

while installing tensorflow,using

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I got the following error

```
tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What does this convey? Is my hardware support adequate?

the output of

```
uname -a
```

is

```
Linux snow-Aspire-4738Z 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 16:13:17 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which arch is your OS? `uname -a`

Comment: @Bahamut see the post for arch information you asked for

Comment: According to github it is not for 32-bit suitable https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/96